# Uniformly continuous derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f:[a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f$ and $f'$ are uniformly continuous in $(a,b)$. Is it true then that $f'$ is continuous at a?

Note: By $f'(a)$ I mean $\lim_{h\to0^{+}}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$.

Comment: Suggestion: Do you know of any nice properties (such as endpoint behavior) possessed by uniformly continuous functions on open or half-open intervals?

Comment: Well, yes... a continuous function in [a,b) uniformly continuous in (a,b) is uniformly continuous in [a,b). But I don't see how this helps, or maybe you mean another property?

Comment: I was hinting at the first property RRL mentions: A uniformly continuous function on a real interval extends continuously to the closure. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

(1)    Show that $f'(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence when $x_n \to a+$. Show $\lim_{x \to a+} f'(x) = L $ exists uniquely.

(2) Use the mean value theorem

$$ \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(\xi)$$